# Can't get search results ajax, html

Tags: html, node.js, ajax, express

So what i am trying to do here is searching users by their id, but the code isnt working, it says id_needle is undefined which I'm not sure why, did I do something wrong here? Please help look through to see what mistakes I'm making. I have been staring at this for 1 hour...Thank you in advance!

This is my script inside my html

```
    function createCard(cardInfo) {
        let cardHtml = `<div class="card" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">${cardInfo.username}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    ${cardInfo.email}
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    <a href="viewUsers.html?userid=${cardInfo.uid}" class="btn btn-primary" 
                     class="View">View</a>           
                </div>
            </div>`;

        return cardHtml;
    }


    function searchByIDContains() {

        console.log("-----------Search User------------")
        //  console.log(`Needle: ${id_needle}`);

        var tmpToken = localStorage.getItem('token');

        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'authorization': 'Bearer ' + tmpToken },

            url: 'http://localhost:8081/user/search',

            type: 'POST',

            data: JSON.stringify(id_needle),

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (postmanResponse, textStatus, xhr) {

                console.log("-----------ajax::serachuser::success---------------")
                console.log(postmanResponse);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(xhr);


                postmanResponse.forEach(userObj => {
                    //compile the data the card needss for its creation
                    let cardInfo = {
                        "uid": userObj.userid,
                        "username": userObj.username,
                        "email": userObj.email,
                    };

                    // console.log("-----------[Card Info data pack]---------");
                    // console.log(cardInfo);

                    let newCard = createCard(cardInfo);

                    $("#users").append(newCard);
                })
            },

            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                console.log("-----------ajax::serachuser::failed---------------")
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console(errorThrown);
                console.log('Error in Operation');

                $('#msg').html('Error in Operation!');

                
            }
        });
    }



    $(document).ready(function () {
        //extract the query params, if any
        let queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

        console.log("-----Query Params--------");
        console.log(`Query Param (source): ${window.location.search}`);
        console.log(`Query Param (extracted): ${queryParams}`);

        if (queryParams.has("search")) {
            let id_needle = queryParams.get("search");
            //loadUser(uid);
            searchByIDContains(id_needle)

            //console.log("loading a single user..")
        }
        else {
            loadAllUsers();
        }
        //loadAllUsers();

        $("#Search").click(function () {
            console.log("Search button is clicked");

            let searchPhrase = $("#searchContents").val();

            console.log(`Search Phrase: ${searchPhrase}`);

            let redirectUrl = `http://localhost:3001/viewUsers.html?search=${searchPhrase}`;

            window.location.assign(redirectUrl);
            //disable the form submission
            return false
        })
    });
```

This is my html file

```
   <div style="margin-top: 2rem;">

        <h1>Home</h1>

        <p><span id="msg" class="debug"></span></p>

        <form id="search-user-form" style="margin-top: 2rem;">

            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="searchContents" rows="3" 
                   placeholder="Search what?"></textarea>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Search">Search User by 
             ID</button>

        </form>

        <div id="users">


        </div>

    </div>
```

My user.js

```
  searchByIDContains: function (id_needle, callback) {

    var dbConn = db.getConnection();


    dbConn.connect(function (err) {

      if (err) {
        console.log("connection error")
        console.log(err);
        return callback(err, null);
      }

      else {

        const sql = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid LIKE "%${id_needle}%"`;
        dbConn.query(sql, [id_needle], (error, resultSet) => {
          dbConn.end();
          if (error) {
            console.log(" query error")
            return callback(error, null);

          }

          console.log(resultSet);

          //can potentially return back empty array
          // if no result is found

            return callback(null, resultSet);

     


        });
      }
    });
  }
```

My app.js

```
app.post("/user/search", function (req, res) {

  let id_needle = req.body.input_needle

    user.searchByIDContains(id_needle, function (err, result) {
       if (err) {
       
        res.status(500).send("error");
        res.end();
       }
         else {
           if (result) {
            
            res.status(200).send(result);
            res.end();
             }

          else {
            res.status(200).send("No user found!");
            res.end();
          }

    }
});
```

});

Comment: function searchByIDContains(id_needle) { }
you have to add parameter in function

Comment: hi, thx for answering so I tried what u said but i got this error instead  SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0